# Exclude holidays in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

table1 K

```
Date          id
2015-01-01    10
2015-01-02    10
2015-01-03    10
2015-01-04    10
2015-01-05    10
2015-01-06    10
```

table2 H

```
Date          id   Holiday
2015-01-03    10   a holiday day
```

I want to exclude holidays from my `Date` column and create a new column like `AS new_dates`.
So the output is like:

table3 Output

```
new_dates     id
2015-01-01    10
2015-01-02    10
2015-01-04    10
2015-01-05    10
2015-01-06    10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now edited.
I was suggesting `EXCEPT ALL`, but Oracle has `MINUS` instead, according to MTO's answer.

```
select date, id from table1
MINUS
select date, id from table2
```

Or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select date, id from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2
                  where t1.date = t2.date
                    and t1.id = t2.id)
```

**Edited**: added `and t1.id = t2.id` to the `NOT EXISTS` version's sub-select.

Comment: `EXCEPT ALL` is not valid SQL in Oracle. The second query will exclude holidays even if the `ID` column is different (so does not achieve the same result as the first query if you were to correct the syntax).

Comment: `EXCEPT` is supported in sql server and not in Oracle.

Comment: @MTO, I'm not sure the id value matters in the NOT EXISTS answer. If a date is a holiday regardless of id, that date is always a holiday! (Or?)

Comment: If the `ID` represents a country/religion then you can have holidays on different days depending on the different `ID`s. The main point was that the first and second queries you give are not equivalent.

Comment: @jarlh The MINUS query considers both `DATE` and `ID`, while your `NOT EXISTS` query is only considering `DATE`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll wait and see OP adds info about the id column.

Comment: @MT0ID @jarlh `ID` indeed represents a country. The holidays are excluded on all the ID columns with the NOT EXISTS query, i have 4 different `ID`s in my table. If one `ID` has an holiday, all dates will excluded for the `ID` in the output. With NOT EXISTS i cant query this for seperate ID's?

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
select date, id from table1 
where not exists(select 'x' from table2 where table1.date = table2.date)
```

Comment: This will exclude holidays even if the `ID` columns are different.

Comment: @MT0 If it need this condition can be added in exists part, but as far as I know same structures matters only date.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9a55/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( "DATE", ID ) AS
SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' + LEVEL - 1, 10
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 7;

CREATE TABLE T2 ( "DATE", ID ) AS
SELECT DATE '2015-01-03', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM T2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9a55/2/0)**:

```
|                      DATE | ID |
|---------------------------|----|
| January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 04 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 05 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 06 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                   FROM   T2
                   WHERE  T1.ID = T2.ID
                   AND    T1."DATE" = T2."DATE" )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9a55/2/1)**:

```
|                      DATE | ID |
|---------------------------|----|
| January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 05 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 04 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 06 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
| January, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 10 |
```

**Query 3**:

This query is valid in SQL Server but not in Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT * FROM T2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9a55/2/2)**:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way,

```
SQL> SELECT t1.* FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1."DATE" <> t2."DATE" AND t1.ID = t2.ID;

DATE              ID
--------- ----------
01-JAN-15         10
02-JAN-15         10
04-JAN-15         10
05-JAN-15         10
06-JAN-15         10
```

There could be different holidays for different IDs, so the condition checks for unmatched rows and filters them out and makes sure it is checked for a particular ID and not random.

From a **performance point of view**, with proper primary and foreign key constraints, you could do a single table scan on the referencing table rather than 2 table scans.

For example,

Adding the **primary key** and **foreign key** constraints:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t1
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY ("DATE", id);

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t2
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT t2_fk
  3     FOREIGN KEY ("DATE", ID)
  4     REFERENCES t1 ("DATE", id);

Table altered.
```

Let's check the **explain plan**:

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL> SELECT t1.* FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1."DATE" <> t2."DATE" AND t1.ID = t2.ID;

DATE              ID
--------- ----------
01-JAN-15         10
02-JAN-15         10
04-JAN-15         10
05-JAN-15         10
06-JAN-15         10


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 603358195

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |     5 |   110 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS      |       |     5 |   110 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2    |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX FULL SCAN  | T1_PK |     5 |    55 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."ID")
       filter("T1"."DATE"<>"T2"."DATE" AND "T1"."ID"="T2"."ID")

Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

So, there is a **full table scan** only on `T2` and an **INDEX FULL SCAN** on the primary key index of `T1`.

Now, there should be a supporting index for the foreign key, which will avoid the **full table scan** and use the **index scan**.

Let's create the **supporting index** for the **foreign key**:

```
SQL> CREATE INDEX t2_indx ON t2("DATE", id);

Index created.
```

Let's check the **explain plan**:

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL> SELECT t1.* FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1."DATE" <> t2."DATE" AND t1.ID = t2.ID;

DATE              ID
--------- ----------
01-JAN-15         10
02-JAN-15         10
04-JAN-15         10
05-JAN-15         10
06-JAN-15         10


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2278991468

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |     5 |   110 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS    |         |     5 |   110 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| T2_INDX |     1 |    11 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| T1_PK   |     5 |    55 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("T1"."ID"="T2"."ID")
       filter("T1"."DATE"<>"T2"."DATE" AND "T1"."ID"="T2"."ID")

Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

Now, there are no **full table scans**, rather optimizer uses **INDEX FULL SCAN**.

Comment: This will only work if there is one row in `T2` with the same `ID` as the one you are searching for. If `T2` has no rows for an `ID` then this will exclude all rows of `T1` for that `ID`.

Comment: @MTO Per OP's design, he is maintaining the holiday date for each ID in separate table. So, for date value for a particular ID, when a match is found it is not selected. So, this works exactly the way OP explained the requirement.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21556/1 - Create `T1` with `ID`s 9 and 10 and Create `T2` with only rows with `ID` 10 - this query will not return any of the rows with `ID = 9`. Queries using `MINUS` and `NOT EXISTS` will return those rows.

Comment: Well, then OP needs to explain his design. My solution is based on the fact that for each ID there will be at least one row in the other table.